# ckeditor cant upload file while using replaceall

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor, ckeditor4

I use 2 ck editor in one page, I use code :

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"\>
CKEDITOR.replaceAll('ckcreate', {
filebrowserUploadUrl: "{{route('admin.berita.upload', \['\_token' =\> csrf_token() \])}}",
filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form'
});
</script\>
```

only one ckeditor can upload image, another ckeditor not show tab uploads.

how I can fix it?

laravel 8

sorry for my bad english.

?